# How can I verify that a PGP key is imported into RPM?

Tags: rpm, gpg

One can import a key with:

> rpm --import /path/to/key

But how can you tell later if you have already imported this key? Trying to reimport it will fail with an error and I am trying to avoid this as I am using Puppet to install the key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can double check if a key is already imported using `rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-<version>-<release>`. If it is installed, rpm will give you all the information about it, if not, it'll just exit with a return value of 1, so you could add to your puppet recipe an `unless` parameter:

```
exec { "rpm --import /path/to/package":
  # ...
  unless => "rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-<version>-<release> > /dev/null 2>&1"
}
```

Comment: Better way through some code I found: `KEYFILE=/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release; KEYID=$(echo $(gpg --throw-keyids < $KEYFILE)|cut -c11-18|tr [A-Z] [a-z]); rpm -q gpg-pubkey-$KEYID`

Comment: The cut ties you to a specific layout, which does not work on my RHEL6 test system.  And gpg now includes sub keys as well as the pub key.  So, I ended up using `KEYID=$(gpg --throw-keyids $KEYFILE | sed -n '/^pub/s|^[^/]*/\([[:alnum:]]*\) .*|\1|p' | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]])`

Comment: There's really no need to include the `-i` option to `rpm`. That just makes it print all the details about the package which you promptly send to `/dev/null`. Plain `rpm -q package-name` will do just fine, without the unnecessary verbosity.

Answer (score 5):

Every key imported adds a rpmdb entry of `gpg-pubkey-<left(hex(fingerprint), 8)>-<encoded import date>`. Just check for that name (`gpg-pubkey`) and the appropriate version (the first 8 characters of the key fingerprint in hex) in the rpmdb.

Comment: `rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-FINGERPRINT-\* > /dev/null 2>&1`

(reference, including how to get the `FINGERPRINT`: http://robinbowes.com/article.php/20081107174415581 )

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to verify that the key is imported (without programmatically processing this information) you can list all keys like this:

```
rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-\* | grep -E ^Packager
```

or for the ids:

```
rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-\* | grep -E "^Version  "
```

This may seem quite obvious to many but I suppose for some it is a more direct answer to (at least the headline of) the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me somehow (on Oracle Linux 7) it was necessary to manually copy it into:

`/var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/RPM-GPG-KEY-${REPONAME}.key`

I could even import the pubkey twice with no error message but validation still failed.
But I have not yet found out why. Maybe next time I'll try:

`yum makecache`

Which is reported to help sometimes, I whish I could find some clear documentation as to what goes where and when, instead of having to use strace and Google.

I hope this helps someone...